# How to get DD-WRT (dnsmasq) to serve DNS but *not* DHCP?

Tags: dns, dd-wrt, dnsmasq

I want to configure a `DD-WRT` router just for local `DNS` resolution of a few names, and then fall back to my ISP's `DNS` server. I am using a separate router, the sole purpose of this `DD-WRT` router is as a `DNS` appliance on my LAN. My actual router will take care of `DHCP`.

Is it possible to set up `DD-WRT` for `DNS` service, without `DHCP` service?

Comment: Yes. Uncheck `[  ] dhcp enabled`.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't get DNS responses from the box. Both DNSMasq and Local DNS are "Enabled" on the Services page.

Comment: DIG shows "status: REFUSED" in the answer.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with DNSMasq, but briefly reviewing the documentation - I could be wrong but it seems DNSMasq local DNS resolution works only with it's integrated DHCP server.  So it will only resolve local names it's given out with DHCP.  It may be possible to configure it otherwise.  If your router has enough memory you may look into running BIND on it, or run BIND elsewhere on your network.